# Injection Service Spring on ManagedBean Failed NPE

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsf, primefaces

Using, Spring 3, Hibernate 4, JSF 2.0, PrimeFaces

My Spring config:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.tds.erp"/>
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:spring-configured/>

<!-- Data Source Declaration -->
<bean id="DataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql:/localhost:3306/erp_tsd" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
</bean>

<!-- Session Factory Declaration -->
<bean id="SessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="DataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.tds.erp.model" />
   <!-- <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>net.javabeat.spring.model</value>
        </list>
    </property>-->

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DB2400Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>

<!-- Transaction Manager is defined -->
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

My Web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<!-- Change to "Production" when you are ready to deploy -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Welcome page -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<!-- JSF mapping -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Map these files with JSF -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

FacesConfig.xml:

```
<application>
    <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
</application>
```

ManagedBean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="UserErpMB")
@Scope(value="request")
 public class UserErpManagedBean implements Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   private static final String SUCCESS = "success";
   private static final String ERROR   = "error";

//Spring UserErp Service is injected...
   @ManagedProperty("#{IUserErpService}")
    private IUserErpService iUserErpService ; // getter and setter for this. //THIS IS NULL!
  }
```

**I try to inject UserErpService in my managedBean, but its always be Null!! NPE**

this is my UserErpServiceImpl:

```
@Service
@Transactional (readOnly=true)
public class UserErpServiceImpl implements IUserErpService {

@Autowired
IUserErpDao iuserdao;

@Override
@Transactional (propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=false)
public void addUser(UserErp user) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Service Impl");
    iuserdao.addUser(user);
}
```

I got this exception:

```
nov. 23, 2014 10:48:06 PM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute
AVERTISSEMENT: #{UserErpMB.addUserErp}: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.faces.FacesException: #{UserErpMB.addUserErp}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at   javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.tds.erp.managedController.UserErpManagedBean.addUserErp(UserErpManagedBean.java:68)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:245)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at            javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
... 30 more
```

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved by adding
    @Component
    @ManagedBean
    @SessionScoped

and @Autowired to the service interface:

```
@Component
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UserErpMB {

private static final String SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String ERROR   = "error";

//Spring UserErp Service is injected...
@Autowired
private IUserErpService iUserErpService ; // getter and setter for this.

List<UserErp> usersList;
private int id;
private String name;
private String surname;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the problem:

```
@ManagedProperty("#{IUserErpService}")
```

By default Spring beans have ids as name of the implementation class of the bean (not interface) starting with lowercase letter (unless manually specified otherwise). And in EL you reference the beans by their IDs not interface class. So it should probably be this:

```
@ManagedProperty("#{userErpServiceImpl}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Full answer:

JSF bean:

```
inject spring service
@ManagedProperty("#{handlerService}")
private HandlerService handlerService = null;
///add setter
```

### Spring service:

```
@Service("handlerService")
@Component
public class HandlerService {
    @Autowired
    private DomainService domainService;

faces-config.xml
   <application>     
        <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>                  
    </application>
------------
web.xml

 <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.myspringconfgigclass.CommonCoreConfig</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```