# JSF 2.0 Spring bean injection

Tags: java, spring, jsf-2

I'm using the following spring's jars:

```
spring-web-2.5.5.jar
spring-context-2.5.5.jar
spring-core-2.5.5.jar
spring-orm-2.5.5.jar
spring-support-2.0.8.jar
spring-security-taglibs-2.0.3.jar
spring-security-acl-2.0.3.jar
spring-security-core-2.0.4.jar
spring-aop-2.5.5.jar
spring-jdbc-2.5.5.jar
spring-tx-2.5.5.jar
```

The issue is after migration from `JSF 1.2` to `JSF 2.0` beans, defined in the faces-context cannot be injected into a managed bean with session scope. For instance:

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>bannersController</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>jaxp.com.controller.BannersController</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
        <managed-property>
            <property-name>bannerDao</property-name>
            <value>#{bannerDao}</value>
        </managed-property>
</managed-bean>
```

and

```
<bean id="bannerDao" class="jaxp.com.db.dao.BannerDaoImpl"
    scope="prototype">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sitePartnerSessionFactory" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="sitePartnerDataSource" />
</bean>
```

When I replace the scope of the bean to session it'll work fine. But now, the managed property is just null. It had worked before we migrated to JSF 2.0. What's wrong and how to fix?

**UPD:** If I set managed bean scope to view scope it also works fine/

Comment: Stop mixing different spring versions... Spring 2.5.5 and 2.0.8 don't mix. Also not sure why your dao is prototype scoped, should be singleton imho. Make sure that you have configured the correct resolver for JSF it will only work with proper integration setup...

Comment: See my full answer in label Full answer:
[Spring bean injection to JSF bean][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27094466/injection-service-spring-on-managedbean-failed-npe/27113201#27113201

Answer (score 1):

JSF bean:

```
inject spring service
@ManagedProperty("#{handlerService}")
private HandlerService handlerService = null;
///add setter
Spring service:

@Service("handlerService")
@Component
public class HandlerService {
    @Autowired
    private DomainService domainService;

faces-config.xml
   <application>     
        <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>                  
    </application>
------------
web.xml

 <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.myspringconfgigclass.CommonCoreConfig</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```